# Unit test of a function calling 2 tested functions inside the same class

Tags: java, function, testing, junit

I have the following skeleton of code in a JAVA class called "TestClass.Java":

```
public String functionA () {
    if (function B() == true) {
        String testVariable = function C();
        String test2 = testVariable +"Here a test";
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to apply unit tests for this function functionA() where tests had been applied on functionB() and functionC():
I did below:

```
private TestClass mockTestClass ;
@Test
public void testFunctionA() {
    mockTestClass = Mockito.mock(TestClass.class);
    private MockComponentWorker mockito;
    Mockito.when(mockTestClass.functionB()).thenReturn(true);//already test is done;
    Mockito.when(mockTestClass.functionC()).thenReturn("test"); //already test is done;
    mockito = mockitoContainer.getMockWorker();                 
    mockito.addMock(TestClass.class,mockTestClass);
    mockito.init();
    assertEquals("PAssed!", "test Here a test", mockTestClass.functionA());
}
```

When I ran my test, I got: `NULL` in `mockTestClass.functionA()`.
Can you please help? How to test this function?

Comment: This code cannot compile. Please show your actual code and your actual error if you want helpful responses.

Comment: Ist hard to tell with just fractions of implemented code.
Generally it ist no a good idea to mock function in the same class.

Another hint if you get confused with how to test try the test first approach.

Answer (score 1):

You would generally want to mock other classes and not the class you are actually testing. But for your example if you really want to mock calling `functionB()` and `functionC()` you need to **spy on TestClass**. And instead of `Mockito.when(mockTestClass.functionB()).thenReturn(true)` you need `doReturn(true).when(mockTestClass).functionB()` (same goes for `functionC()`). Only then your `assertEquals("PAssed!", "test Here a test", mockTestClass.functionA())` will call the actual method `functionA()` and pass.

Comment: Thanks AaCodes. I did that but I'm getting TargetInvocationException. Do you think I should separate functions into 2 classes? thanks, Rosy

Comment: Well, if you are working on legacy codes and if you really need to mock out functionB and functionC then spying on the TestClass should do the trick. For example:

`TestClass spyTestClass = Mockito.spy(new TestClass());
doReturn(true).when(spyTestClass).functionB();
assertEquals("called functionB from functionA", spyTestClass.functionA());`

Comment: As for your question of whether to put them in a new class, it depends on the kind of work functionB() or functionC() is doing. If they are providing a significant service put them in a new service class. If they are just helper methods then we should make them private and not even bother to mock them and just unit test functionA().

Comment: Thanks a lot AaCodes, I used spying and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @RosySALAME would you please accept the answer. Thanks.